# SharePoint KeywordQuery - how to sort

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm writing a custom search app.  Currently using the KeywordQuery class.  I can get results fine, but if I try to sort by a custom property, it bombs with:

> Can't sort by pid 400 for one or more
>   of the following reasons:
>   multi-valued: false, binary: false,
>   non-indexed: true.

The following is the code.  Anyone spot the issue?  If i sort by "Rank" it'll work fine, but not if I use a manged property.

```
   KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(proxy);
    query.IgnoreAllNoiseQuery = false;
    query.ResultsProvider = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchProvider.Default;

    //Return following properties           
    query.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("Path");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("SiteDescription");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("SiteKeywords"); //This is a multi-value so will have to be parsed
    query.SelectProperties.Add("SiteType");

    query.SelectProperties.Add("ContentClass");
    query.SelectProperties.Add("SiteName");

    //Query text (WHERE)
    query.QueryText = queryText;

    //Sort
    //Not sure what the criteria is here, but trying to sort by Title does not work.  ULS indicated it may need to be an indexed column?
    query.SortList.Add("Title", Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortDirection.Descending);


    query.ResultTypes |= ResultType.RelevantResults;
    ResultTableCollection searchResults = query.Execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

The managed property has to be set as 'sortable' before the content is crawled. You can use powershell for setting this.

Answer (score 1):

So I've been trying to sort by the "Title" field.  I found that the sort works when I create my own managed property for title, mapped to the same crawl properties as the OOB Title, with "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison." checked.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a managed property it needs to have the option "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison." checked.

Answer (score 0):

Standard **Title** managed property is not sortable